# Dell E5430 BIOS menu says "File System Not Found!" when I click "Add Boot Option"

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, dell-latitude

I have two Dell E5430 laptops, and I'm encountering this problem on both of them:

When I boot up the system I press F12 and then select BIOS settings. Within the BIOS settings I navigate to the page where the Boot Sequence can be configured. On that page there is a set of three buttons

- Add Boot Option
- Delete Boot Option
- View

When I click "Add Boot Option" a "Warning" window pops up and says "File System Not Found!"

Why does the BIOS not allow me to add a boot option?

Please note that I'm *not* asking for information on how to get Windows or Linux booting. There are answers online for fixing those specific scenarios (for example: https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Add-Boot-Option-File-System-Not-Found/td-p/7560973 ). I'm asking why I cannot add UEFI boot entries :-)

Things that I've tried:

- Toggling "Legacy Boot" and "UEFI" back and forth
- Toggling "Allow Legacy ROMs" on and off
- Toggling "Secure Boot" on and off

The BIOS version for both of these machines is A21 (the latest that I could find on Dell's website)

[image: Photo of the error message]

Comment: Why are you trying to add one, they are both already added.

Answer (score 0):

Because in those menus UEFI expects to have some kind of bootable medium (HDD, SSD, or USB) *visible*. You are looking for installed bootloaders and setting the *order*, not telling it what disks to *try* and boot from.  You already have whatever bootloaders your system can find set up.

UEFI is intelligent enough to be able to scan hard disks and USB sticks for bootable systems. It looks for FAT partitions that contain [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) data.

If you do not have a disk or USB stick with a valid EFI bootloader then you will need to boot from one, install an operating system, and *then* I would expect you to see options in those menus.

Those menus are nowhere near as "dumb" as BIOS systems were, where they simply showed you a list of disks they could see and expected you to know which had bootable disks. Modern systems can go out and look for proper bootloaders installed on the disks so you know for certain that you are booting an operating system.

In "Legacy" mode it may well be looking for a valid MBR and active partition on its boot disks before it shows you anything.